# Check to see if function was called?

Tags: swift

How would i go about checking if a function was called? I have created a function to see if the level was completed like so:

```
func levelOneCompleted(){

}
```

When the level one is beat, i call the function levelOneCompleted().

The scene then goes to another scene. It's at this scene that i want to check if the function was called. I am thinking i can make some kind of "if statement".

```
if levelOneCompleted is called {
//do this

else{

//do this
}
```

What would be the best way of going about this?

Answer (score 5):

Set a boolean flag to `true` inside `levelOneCompleted()`:

```
var isLevelOneCompleted = false

func levelOneCompleted(){
    // do things...
    isLevelOneCompleted = true
}
```

And later...

```
if isLevelOneCompleted {
    //do this
} else {
    //do this
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! Is there a way to do this on two separate scenes? Scene 1 calls the function and switches to scene 2. Can scene 2 see the function from scene 1?

Comment: @MattCantrelle How is scene 2 being presented? Using a storyboard segue? If so I would set a property in the view controller indicating that `levelOneCompleted()` was called in the `prepareForSegue` method.

Comment: No sir, I actually don't use storyboards for for this project. In the first scene, I have set what the second scene is through a simple "let sceneTwo = SKscene(filenamed: "this")". I then call it to present the scene.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with SceneKit but could you create a subclass of `SKScene` and add a property? Then you could do `sceneTwo.isLevelOneCompleted = true` before presenting it.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3 & Xcode 8.3.2**

There is 2 trick to do this, here is the code:

```
// Async operation
func levelOneCompleted(completion: (_ completed: Bool) -> Void) {
    // do your function here
    completion(true)
}

// Here is how to use it
// than u can declare this in viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear, everywhere you name it
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // this is async operation
    levelOneCompleted { (completed) in
        if completed {
            print("levelOneCompleted is complete")
            // do something if levelOneCompleted is complete

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // Update your UI
            }
        } else {
            print("levelOneCompleted is not completee")
            // do something if levelOneCompleted is not complete

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // Update your UI or show an alert
            }
        }
    }
}


// Or u can use this code too, and this is Sync operation
var isLevelTwoCompleted: Bool = false
func levelOneCompleted() {
    // do your function here
    isLevelTwoCompleted = true
}


// to check it u can put this function everywhere you need it
if isLevelTwoCompleted {
    //do something if level two is complete
} else {
    //do something if level two is  not complete
}
```

Comment: Hi Matt, I'm wondering if this was enough to get you on the right track. It looks like it will work if you call level one and level two from the same controller.  If you're still stuck, just edit your question above.